# Graphing Two Lines as if they are the Same

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I'm trying to graph two lines on the same X axis. I have the following two columns:

```
1   400
2   500
3   200
----------------
4   560
5   100
6   604
```

Above the divider is one line, below the divider is another line. But the numbers 1-6 need to be on the horizontal axis. The reason I'm doing two separate lines is that they represent normal and extrapolated data, respectively, so I need to style them differently.

The problem I'm having is that, since I'm using the same X axis for two different lines, the 560 ends up being put at the number 1 instead of 4.

Is there any sort of MANUAL graphing in Excel? It'd make it easier if Excel didn't assume it knows best sometimes.

How can I graph this data in this way?

Comment: How about putting the extrapolated data in a different column.  So B1-3 is real and C4-6 is extrapolated.  If you chart them with a line graph then they will appear different colours.

Comment: But will they appear end to end this way?

Comment: The will if you have the last "real" column replicated in the first "extrapolates" column (or use a midpoint average of the two)

Comment: I've tried it (possibly incorrectly) here: http://i.imgur.com/YtAwy52.png and the lines themselves are not lining up as I'd like them to (end to end, as if one continues from the other). EDIT: trying in 2013 currently as I'm on a different machine at the moment, but I think it'll perform the same for such a simple task...

Comment: X shouldn't be a series, it should be the labels...

Comment: Yes, sorry. When I modify it to be that way, however, the other two lines remain as you see them.